# Angular2: DynamicComponentLoader with component which uses <ng-content></ng-content>

Tags: angular

I need to use DynamicComponentLoader to load a component. Basically, this works using `loadNextToLocation(MyFormComponent, ...)`. But `MyFormComponent` uses `<ng-content>` in its template, and this causes Angular to throw an exception (message: „The component ... has 1 `<ng-content>` elements, but only 0 slots were provided.“)

Is there some way to programmatically handle this, i.e. to define an HTML fragment to be used for `<ng-content>`?

Comment: Is this on the root component?

Comment: No. The `loadNextToLocation` call is inside a component which is not the root.

Comment: I guess a Plunker would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was surprisingly tricky to solve. The current syntax for DCL just isn't very conducive to this sort of thing.

Turns out that you can pass an innerElement or a nativeElement to the DCL call:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bar',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class Bar {}

@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: `
    <div #getThis>I'm gonna be injected!</div>
  `
})
export class Foo implements ngAfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('getThis') getThis;

  constructor (
    private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader,
    private _er: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit () {
    this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(Bar, this._er, null, null, [[this.getThis.internalElement]]);
  }
}
```

As you can see, however, this implies a pre-prepared element. If you want dynamic HTML, you'll probably have to do something along these lines for the `foo` template.

```
<div #getThis [innerHTML]="myHTML"></div>
```

And fill it with your component.